# Pronunciation of the phonetic symbol /ʌ/

Tags: pronunciation

The phonetics of the word **consultant** is /kənˈsʌltənt/. My ears heard the part /ʌl/ is exactly the same as the word **so** /soʊ/. So the question is that both /ʌl/ and /oʊ/ are the same pronunciation, isn't it?

Comment: I pronounce them differently. I would find it very strange to hear one pronounced in the same way as the other.

Comment: It depends a lot on the person's accent. *ul* *al* can come out a bit like ow in a London accent. I don't think it's exactly the same as the vowel in so but I could understand if you heard a similarity. I can't think of any other accent where they are alike.

Answer (score 1):

In general, /ʌl/ and /oʊ/ are not pronounced the same.

Vowels before the /l/ sound are prone to merging with other vowel sounds. Most of these vowel mergers occur in some accents, but not in others.

Related to this, in some accents, the /l/ sound itself may be "vocalized", turning into a semivowel or glide like [w] or [ʊ].

So it's not too strange that the *ul* of *consultant* and the *o* of *so* sound the same to you. But this is not considered to be the "standard" pronunciation of words like *consultant,* because many speakers still use different pronunciations for *ul* and *o*.

Comment: I got the difference, especially for these 3 words: `so`, `consultant` and `sound`. The /ʌl/ is sitting somewhere between /əʊ/ and /aʊ/. Thank you!